# Question about definition of Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to understand the following definition:

[image]

which can also be found [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~einsiedl/FA-lecture.pdf) on page 136.

Question 1: Closure with respect to what norm? It's not given in the definition.

Question 2: Do I have this right: I can view $C^\infty$ as a dense subspace of $H^k$ via the map (embedding) $f \mapsto (D^\alpha f)_\alpha$ where the tuple $f$ is mapped to consists of all derivatives $D^\alpha f$ such that $|\alpha| \leq k$. Then this is cool because if we have this we can extend any linear operator $T: C^\infty \to C^n$ continuously to all of $H^k$ so that anything we can do to smooth functions we can also do to Sobolev functions. That is, even if the functions don't have a strong $\alpha$-th derivative we can treat them as if they did.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The picture is not very clear:)

Comment: I'll hazard a wild guess that we probably want to use the $L^2$ norm to complete to something we'll be calling an $L^2$ space.

Comment: By definition $V$ is a product of $K(k)$ $L^2$-spaces. It should be a Hilbert space, so there's only one candidate. Give it the norm that it should have, find the definition also given in Def. 3.50.

Comment: @t.b. Thank you! So the $\ell^2$-norm, I see. And what about question 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. We can endow $V$ with the norm 
   $$\lVert (v_j)_{1\leq j\leq K(k)}\rVert_V:=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{K(k)}\lVert v_j\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb T^d)}^2}$$
   (it's an usual norm in product of $L^2$ spaces).
2. Yes, by definition $C^{\infty}(\mathbb T^d)$ is dense in its closure. When you say "anything we can do with smooth function, we can do it for Sobolev functions", careful. The property true for smooth functions has to be preserved by taking the limit in $\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$.

Comment: Thank you! And how do I know whether a property is preserved by taking the limit?

Comment: I don't think there is a general criteria. We have to discuss each case individually.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure: does taking the limit mean that we have a sequence of $f_n$ in $C^\infty$ such that all the $\alpha$-th derivatives with $|\alpha| \leq k$ are in $L^2$, that is, $(D^\alpha f)_\alpha \in H^k$ and then we want $f$ to have the property that all $f_n$ have where $\| f_n - f \|_\infty \to 0$?

Comment: I would take $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_V$ to $0$ rather than the supremum norm, but yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Sorry I am very confused. There is a theorem that if $A$ is a dense subspace of $B$ and $T: A \to C$ is a continuous and linear operator then $T$ uniquely and continuously extends to all of $B$. Now if we take $A= C^\infty$, $B= H^k$ and $C=C^l$ then this would mean that I can do anything I can do to smooth functions $C^\infty \to C^l$, I can also do to Sobolev functions $H^k \to C^l$. What am I missing?