# If $u(.,t) \in H^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $u (.,t) \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The statement is as such:

> $u \in L^2([0,T]; H^2(\mathbb{R}))$ for any $T>0$, thus $u (.,t) \in
> > C^1(\mathbb{R})$ a.e. in $t>0$.

- My guess was that this must be a result of Sobolev embedding. We know $W^{2,2} (\mathbb{R})$ can be continuously embedded in the space $C^{1,1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ since $W^{1,2} (\mathbb{R})$ continuously embeds into $C^{0,1/2}(\mathbb{R})$. However, I do not know how to show from here that this would mean that for any $t>0$, $u (.,t) \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ a.e.
- Also, why "almost everywhere?"

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182798/question-about-sobolev-embedding-theorem?rq=1), they are working on a torus, and I have not yet encountered an embedding theorem like this in my course. Additionally, in my setting, I am not on a compact or bounded domain.

Comment: To be $C^1$ is a local property, you can always multiply your function by a smooth function that is $1$ near the point where you are testing the $C^1$ character

Comment: A function in $L^2(0, T; H^2 )$ is an $L^2$ function of time with values in the Banach space $H^2$, and hence is defined only for a.e. $t$. Since, by the Sobolev embedding $H^2 \hookrightarrow C^1$, $u(t) \in C^1$ for a.e. $t$.

Comment: @LL3.14 I'm sorry, I don't follow. I understand that differentiability is a local property, but what does "testing the $C^1$ character" mean?

Comment: Looking if the function is $C^1$ at that point.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\int_0^T\|u(\cdot, t)\|_{H^2(\mathbb{R})}^2dt<\infty$$ and so for a.e. $t$ it follows that $$\|u(\cdot, t)\|_{H^2(\mathbb{R})}^2<\infty.$$ This just follows from the fact that if you have a non-negative function $f$ whose integral is finite, then the function $f$ can assume the value $\infty$ at most on a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Now for every good $t$, you use the embedding theorem.